# Minecraft Plugin Coding, Towny Hook into My Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

*Probably not the best place to ask this, but if any of you code minecraft plugins then you can probably take a look :)*

**This is a minor issue, and i do not need a quick response. All i want to ask is how do i hook towny into my plugin. What i want to do is replacing the towny commands "Such as /town new " with my command "/town create "
I am not that of an expert, so here is my code so far:**

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
Player p = (Player) sender;
 if (args.length == 0) {
sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&c/town create <navn>"));
 sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&c/town delete>"));
 sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&c/town money"));
} else if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("lag")) {

 p.performCommand("town new " + args[1]);
 p.sendMessage(Addons.tcc(Addons.prefix() + " &7Du lagde byen " + args[1]));
 p.getWorld().playSound(p.getLocation().add(0.0D, 1.0D, 0.0D), Sound.LEVEL_UP, 50.0F, 0.0F);
}
 return false;
}
```

It seems like when i type the command ingame it says i created the town, but whenever i type /t (Which opens town info) it says i am not apart of a town.
If anyone can help me out i would greatly appriciate it.

Comment: Import Towny into your project and have a look at Townys API ([http://palmergames.com/javadoc/towny-bukkit/](Javadoc)) to see what you can use. Also your code doesn't show any `/town create` command handler. If you override towny you should still make sure to hand your commands over properly.

Comment: Sorry for no response. It worked actually. Thank you!